# Strange behaviour from FTPWebRequest-Class

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I noticed a strange behaviour when using the FtpWebRequest-Class. I want to create a FtpWebRequest to get some data from German Weather Service. So I do sth. like the following:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
request.Credentials = Credentials;
var response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
```

With this code I'm getting following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication
>   Required

This is quite clear and I thought add a Proxy will fix this, but I found something strange then. This code is working:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
request.Credentials = Credentials;
request.Proxy = null;
var response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
```

Is someone out there who can explain me this? I used debugger to be save Proxy is null in both cases. Why I don't get the error message in the second case or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `WebRequest` uses the system-wide proxy (the one defined in IE settings). If that proxy requires credentials, you need to provide them. By setting `Proxy` to null, you bypass the proxy completely, using a direct connection.

You can see this in [the code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/FtpWebRequest.cs). When you set the proxy, it [sets a private `m_ProxyUserSet`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/FtpWebRequest.cs,457) flag to true, which is [checked later](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/FtpWebRequest.cs,487) when deciding the actual proxy to use. If you didn't explicitly specify a proxy, it implicitly uses `WebRequest.InternalDefaultWebProxy`